# SDL - TTF - font not loading

Tags: c++, sdl, truetype

I am having Problem loading SDL_TTF font.

my program is so big, so there's a piece of code which is creating problem.

```
TTF_Font *font = NULL;
SDL_Color textColor = {255, 255, 255};

if(SDL_Init() == -1 || TTF_Init() == -1)
   return 0;

font = TTF_OpenFont("calibri.ttf", 28);
if(font == NULL)
   return 0;
```

Now please tell me why the funtion TTF_OpenFont is not working.
font remains NULL after the funtion and the program exits...

EDIT:
I cannot cout or printf TTF_GetError() but i used breakpoints to see which function is not working correctly and found the function TTF_OpenFont() returning null every time.
(BTW if there any way to print the Erroe on screen the tell please).
TTF_Init() is working correctly.
FOR PEOPLE WHO ARE ASKING TO INSTALL SDL_TTF SEPARATELY:
I have written the link below from which i am learning SDL in first tutorial it guides how to install SDL and integrate it which project, In 3rd lesson comes the SDL_IMAGE extension library which is to be needed to install separately (which i did and used all image functions easily), In 7th lesson it didn't teach how to install SDL_TFF rather says to do the same steps as for SDL_IMAGE but this time for SDL_TTf so i downloaded SDL_TTF and intalled and you know the rest after....

Windows 8.1, CodeBlocks, MinGW32, SDL1
Here's the link i am learning SDL from
[SDL Tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/)
This is how i installed the Extension Library(SDL_TTF)
[Setting Up Extention Library](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/codeblocks/index.php)

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: in 99.9% of cases of resources not loading it is because they exist but not in the correct location

Comment: Q: Did you get it figured out?  Q: Did you check for TTF_Init() errors, as recommended below?  Q: Are you on Linux, Windows or "something else"?  Which compiler: GCC, MSVS or "something else"?  Q: Did you build from source?  SDL TTF 2.0, from [here](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/)?

Comment: Please see the edits.

Comment: Dude - look at the .zip file.  Do you see TTF anywhere in the .zip?  Like I said below - I believe you probably need to install SDL_TTF separately.  PLEASE DO THIS: 1) Modify *BOTH* your TTF_Init() and TTF_OpenFont(), print out TTF_GetError(), and update your post with the error messages. 2) Follow the link below to download and install SDL_TTF.  3) Let us know if it helps.

Comment: please see edits again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED.
Thanks EveryOne for giving your time...
the problem was program was not recognizing font(candara )
so it copy pasted in my project folder.

Comment: This, this, this. Is the expected behaviour of TTF_OpenFont that it'll only look in the project directory?

Comment: I think no, it can lookup into your C:\Windows\Fonts

Answer (score 3):

If `font` is `NULL` you should use [TTF_GetError](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_12.html) to know what went wrong.

If the error message is *opaque* you may want then to take a look at [TTF_OpenFont](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/file/392ca544f5a2/SDL_ttf.c#l368) source.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions:

1) substitute this code for TTF_Init():

```
if(TTF_Init()==-1) {
    printf("TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
    exit(2);
}
```

2) Make sure you call it *before* any other SDL_ttf functions.

If you're still having problems, please specify

- your platform (Windows?  Linux?)
- how you installed your TTF fonts.

3) See also: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html

===================================================================

I'm sorry you're still having problems displaying fonts.  A few additional suggestions:

1) I'm sure the tutorial you're using is very good.  But you can't assume that just because you followed all the steps, you didn't inadvertantly miss something.  To resolve the problem, you're going to have to "look beyond" the tutorial.

2) For starters, we need to confirm whether or not TTF_Init() succeeded. We must be able to see TTF_Init() return status, and TTF_GetError() messages.

Q: What is the return value of TTF_Init?

There are several ways you can display "TTF_GetError":

- Start your program from a command prompt ("cmd"):`printf("TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());`
- Copy the error to a string and look at it under a debugger: `char[80] msg; strcpy (msg, TTF_GetError());`
- Use a Win32 MessageBox to display the error in a pop-up: [MSDN - MessageBox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

3) Make sure you have these .dll's on your filesystem:

- libfreetype*.dll
- SDL2_ttf*.dll
- zlib*.dll

4) Look at the fonts you have installed on your filesystem, for example: `C:\Windows\Fonts\*.ttf`

See also [SDL_ttf - Font directory/Where do fonts go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145683/sdl-ttf-font-directory-where-do-fonts-go)

Comment: 1) The link you cited looks like it just installs SDL - I believe you need to install SDL TTF separately.,  Grab SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.12-mingw.tar.gz  from here: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/.  2) Please to modify your TTF_Init() call per the above, and update your post with the TTF_GetError() output.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was already answerd but i ran into a similar problem with SDL2_ttf under Visual Studio 2015 and want to share my solution to help maybe others in the future.

My problem was that when i started my SDLe application that used SDLe_ttf it could not load the font that was placed in the same directory. But when i executed the the build executable manualy from the command line everything was fine.

I think the problem is that Visual Studio 2015 executes the build executable from a different directory and since i used only the font file name(Sans.ttf) it could not load the font because it treats it as a relative path.

My soultion was to just prefix the font file name with the execution directory which can be optained by calling [SDL_GetBasePath](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetBasePath).